# Cannot execute owned file on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, file-permissions, sudo, user-permissions

I have a file I need to execute as `userme`. The following command runs just fine:

```
# sudo /usr/lib/squid3/squid_radius_auth -f /etc/squid3/radius-config
```

However, when I run as `userme`, it gives the following error:

```
# sudo -u userme /usr/lib/squid3/squid_radius_auth -f /etc/squid3/radius-config
sudo: unable to execute /usr/lib/squid3/squid_radius_auth: Permission denied
```

I have tried these:

```
# sudo chown userme:userme /usr/lib/squid3/squid_radius_auth
# sudo chmod 777 /usr/lib/squid3/squid_radius_auth
# sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/squid3/squid_radius_auth
```

but this doesn't work. I just cant get it to run as non-root.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/219856):

> It is not enough to have read permission on a file in order to read
>   it. You also need to have read permission on the directory it belongs
>   to.

The solution here was:

```
chmod 775 /usr/lib/squid3/
```

Comment: *No no no.* Making a system resource world-writable is a **terrible** idea.  You should immediately revert to sane permissions (perhaps `chmod 755 /usr/lib/squid3`) and take it from there.

Comment: Updated to be more sensible.